# How to show all databases and all their tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to make a PHP script to show all databases, and then to show every tables of each database. Here is what I have done so far, but I need something shorter, not with so many variables (functions and other languages are excluded):

```
$Cerere1="SHOW DATABASES";
$Cerere2="SHOW TABLES FROM `auth`";
$Cerere3="SHOW TABLES FROM `auth1`";
if( $db_list=mysql_query($Cerere1,$con) ) {
    $db_tables1=mysql_query($Cerere2,$con);
    $db_tables2=mysql_query($Cerere3,$con);
while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($db_tables1) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($db_tables2) )
    {

    }
```

If its possible to make a single SHOW TABLES structure, and in case I have 2 databases with 2 tables each, to put the structure into a single query, or something like that.. and yes I know mysql is deprecated, but I have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can `SHOW DATABASES`, and loop through the result set.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
$strSQL = "SHOW DATABASES";
$resGet = mysql_query($strSQL, $con);

echo "Number of Databases:". mysql_num_rows($resGet) . PHP_EOL;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resGet)) {
   $strSQL = "SHOW TABLES FROM ". $row['Database'];
   $resGet2 = mysql_query($strSQL, $con);
   echo "<h3>". mysql_num_rows($resGet2) ." Tables in ". $row['Database'] ."</h3>
           <ul>";
   while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resGet2) ) {
       echo "<li>". $row2['Tables_in_'. $row['Database']] ."</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

Example output:

[image: output]